# On Close of BootstrapDialog, html body tag destroyed; blank page rendered

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-dialog

Calling BootstrapDialog.Show.  Upon clicking the only button 'Ok' which closes dialog, blank page is rendered.

Inspecting the code in browser (Chrome), I see that upon calling BootstrapDialog.Show, the body tag gains a class='modal-open'.  Upon clicking 'Ok' button in bootstrap dialog, dialog closes AND the html  tag is removed from the page.  Only the Header tag is left on the _Layout.cshtml.

I expect to stay on the original page from which the bootstrap dialog was opened!

> > More info<<

In a nutshell, I have an index.cshtml page which opens a partial view.  Within this partial view there is a button that once clicked runs some javascript that checks some stuff and calls the bootstrap dialog if necessary as an alert.  This works great until I close the dialog.

Here's the javascript that calls the bootstrap dialog:

```
$('#btnEdit').click(function () {
        btnClicked = "edit";
        var grid = $('#gridContactList').data('kendoGrid');
        var selectedContact = grid.selectedKeyNames();

        if (!selectedContact.length) { selectedContact = 0; }

        if (selectedContact == 0) {
            //alert("Please select a contact to edit!");
            var message = "Please select a contact to edit!";
            //alert(message);               
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                type: "type-warning",
                title: "Warning!",
                message: message,
                autodestroy: true,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        label: 'OK',
                        action: function (dialogRef) {
                            dialogRef.close();
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
            return;
        }

        $("#winContactSummary").data("kendoWindow").center(true).open();
     })
```

This BootstrapDialog is written by nakupanda...

Comment: you are going to want to post some code to get help on this

Answer (score 0):

based on what i found you need to setup the HTML to have the proper class layout
something along this lines should work, if you provide your HTML or a sample of it I would be able to better help

```
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="bootstrap-dialog-header">
                    <div class="bootstrap-dialog-close-button" style="display: block;"><button class="close">×</button></div>
                    <div class="bootstrap-dialog-title" id="2a6beb12-e208-4c63-8ffc-760a4040deb7_title">Say-hello dialog</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="bootstrap-dialog-body">
                    <div class="bootstrap-dialog-message">Hi Apple!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="display: none;">
                <div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

sample HTML above comes from here 
https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/